# How do I use jQuery to parse XML as I have here

Tags: jquery, xml

This (or some variation of it) is output by my PHP script Notice that some tags use the same name in different contexts:

```
<conversations>
  <status>1</status>
  <conversation>
    <open>0</open>
    <status>1</status>
    <priority>1</priority>
  </conversation>
  <conversation>
    <open>1</open>
    <status>0</status>
    <priority>0</priority>
  </conversation>
</conversations>

<messages>
  <status>1</status>
  <message>
    <msgID>165</msgID>
    <userID>16></userID>
    <msg>How do I parse this?</msg>
  </message>
</messages>
```

First, I need to loop through  and display a button for each conversation. Then I need to loop through  and display all the new messages for the selected conversation. I can figure the logic out on my own. I just don't know how to parse (climb around) the XML. Thanks for your help!

EDIT: If I say $("status",xml).text() how do I know which < status > tag is being referenced? I need to distinguish between < conversations > and < messages >.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `.filter()` to filter through nodes at the top level,
- `.children()` with an optional selector to get a set of immediate children of those at the top level
- `.find()` with a selector to get a set of nodes at any level beneath those at the current top level
- `.each()` to iterate over those at the current top level

---

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/MTPdw/1/

```
var $xml = $(xml);

var conversations = $xml.filter('conversations');

conversations.children('conversation').each(function() {
    alert($(this).find('status').text());
});
```

When you were doing:

```
$("status",xml).text()
```

...it gets converted into this:

```
$(xml).find("status").text();
```

Because the nodes at the top level are `<conversations>` and `<messages>`, it is searching for all `<status>` elements that are descendants of either of those. The `.text()` then returned their cumulative text content.

Comment: Thanks! Is there supposed to be a $ symbol in front of 'xml'? I thought PHP used $ to define variables, and jQuery didn't.

Comment: @Michael: No. It is a common convention used by jQuery developers to denote a variable that is referencing a jQuery object. I placed it there out of habit. Totally optional. Javascript has no such requirement.

Comment: So when I wrote $("status",xml).text() it didn't really make sense? Or would it just grab the first one?

Comment: @Michael: When you did that, you were getting back a jQuery object with *all* the nested `<status>` elements. Placing the `xml` string as the second argument (the context argument) gives exactly the same result as doing `$(xml).find("status")`. You could have done `$("status",xml).each(function(){ alert($(this).text()); });` to have it alert the text of each one individually.

Comment: I've been through at least 12 different stack overflow pages and not one mentioned something OTHER than find() to get xml elements. Thank you for listing others. The jQuery API's example was overly simple to be of any use. Thank you @user113716.