# take data from xml with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<slider>
    <csliderData1>
        <title>Kung Fu Panda</title>
        <content>In the Valley of Peace, Po the Panda finds himself chosen as the Dragon Warrior despite</content>
        <img>pages/images/slider/a.jpg</img>
    </csliderData1>

    <csliderData2>
        <title>Despicable Me</title>
        <content>Gru is recruited by the Anti-Villain League to help deal with a powerful new super criminal.</content>
        <img>pages/images/slider/b.jpg</img>
    </csliderData2>

    <csliderData3>
        <title>Craigslist Joe</title>
        <content>In a time when America's economy was crumbling and sense of community was in question</content>
        <img>pages/images/slider/c.jpg</img>
    </csliderData3>

    <csliderData4>
        <title>X: Night of Vengeance</title>
        <content>A jaded call-girl. A fledgling hooker. The night from hell.</content>
        <img>pages/images/slider/d.jpg</img>
    </csliderData4>

    <csliderData5>
        <title>Rock of Ages</title>
        <content>A small town girl and a city boy meet on the Sunset Strip, while pursuing their Hollywood dreams</content>
        <img>pages/images/slider/e.jpg</img>
    </csliderData5>
</slider>
```

**Hello guys, How can I take data from xml with jquery?
I want to take this data and put in multidimensional array, like this:**

```
var slideShowContent = Array(
    Array('Kung Fu Panda', 'In the Valley of Peace, Po the Panda finds himself chosen as the Dragon Warrior despite', 'pages/images/slider/a.jpg'), 
    Array('Despicable Me', 'Gru is recruited by the Anti-Villain League to help deal with a powerful new super criminal.', 'pages/images/slider/b.jpg'), 
    Array('Craigslist Joe', "In a time when America's economy was crumbling and sense of community was in question", 'pages/images/slider/c.jpg'), 
    Array('X: Night of Vengeance', 'A jaded call-girl. A fledgling hooker. The night from hell.', 'pages/images/slider/d.jpg'), 
    Array('Rock of Ages', 'A small town girl and a city boy meet on the Sunset Strip, while pursuing their Hollywood dreams.', 'pages/images/slider/e.jpg'));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use jQuery to parse XML as I have here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664684/how-do-i-use-jquery-to-parse-xml-as-i-have-here)

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin: 
https://github.com/josefvanniekerk/jQuery-xml2json ("A simple jQuery plugin that converts XML data, typically from $.ajax requests, to a valid JSON object.")

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work with parsed XML

```
var slideShowContent = $.map($(xml).find('slider').children(), function(node, i) {
    return [[$('title', node).text(), $('content', node).text(), $('img', node).text()]];
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/whzet/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml_data = '[xml_data_here]',
    $slider = $( $.parseXML(xml_data) ).find('slider'),
    slider_data = [];

$slider.children().each(function() {
    var slide = [];
    $(this).children().each(function() {
        slide.push( $(this).text() );
    });

    slider_data.push( slide );
});
```